# Regex lazy matching within group?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to matching something like:

`aabbaCaabaCabCbaCCC`, grouped as `(aabbaCaabaCabCba)(CCC)`, i.e. with any final `C`s matched as a separate group.

I assumed I could use lazy matching somehow, but nothing I've tried worked. For example:

`/(a+|b+|C*?)+(C*)/` and `/(a+|b+|C*)+?(C*)/` match too much or not enough; they include the `CCC` in the first group, or they only match the initial `aa`.

This is in JavaScript by the way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex

```
\b([abC]*?)(C*)\b
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dC0wQ8/3)**

*JS Demo*

```js
var re = /\b([abC]+?)(C*)\b/g;
var str = "aabbaCaabaCabCbaCCC";

if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.writeln("<pre>" + m[1] + "</br>" + m[2] + "</br>" + "</pre>");
}
```

Comment: Hmm, this one only works if I include `^` and `$`. Unfortunately I don't have that luxury since it's in the middle of a line...

Comment: @JosephHumfrey ok, but then think for yourself, which `C` will be the deciding factor?

Comment: @JosephHumfrey in `aabbaCaabaC`, I find two `C`..So one possibility is `(aabba)(C)`..is it wrong?

Comment: @JosephHumfrey It can be handled if its a word, though

Comment: Comment above from @WiktorStribiżew would be better here (:

Comment: @bobblebubble OP is still not clear whether it can be substring or not..that's the reason i also mentioned earlier in my comment that:- _It can be handled if its a word, though_

Comment: I guess perhaps the problem with my question is really that the rule is that 'a' and 'b' cannot follow C, and that's how we know it's the end of the match. And phrased like that, it sounds like I need a negative lookahead. Slightly annoying since my real use case is a bit more complicated than [ab], but I guess I may not have a choice.